# Can rqt_graph visualize nodelets?

Tags: ros, rqt-graph, rostopic, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm debugging a ROS application that intensively uses nodelets. However, I found that rqt_graph cannot visualize nodelets. Neither can other command line tools such as rostopic. I'm wondering whether I'm correct on this point, and if so, is there any other way around? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193429/can-rqt_graph-visualize-nodelets?/) by [Vova Niu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19788/vova-niu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2014-09-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No; it isn't possible to introspect which nodelet within a nodelet manager is publishing or subscribing to a particular topic.

You can work around this by running each nodelet in a standalone nodelet manager, but beware that that can have a pretty significant performance impact, because you'll no longer be using zero-copy message passing between nodelets.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1